# JQGrid: local - jqGrid.trigger("reloadGrid") makes formatted data disappear

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid and using loadonce: true

when add filter and call reloadGrid.

The cells with custom formatter will not display data.. In this case they are radio buttons.

may I know how can I resolve this issue?

when it inspect the cell.. the data is empty. and the formatter was not called during reloadGrid

Comment: Do you have both Format and UnFormat functions defined?

Comment: only formatter : formatRadio

Answer (score 1):

Yo probably should also setup an unformat function where based on your radio button selection state you return your original value that was passed to the JQgrid as a data (i assume it is boolean value)
it will probably be something like this:

```
 function unformatRadio(cellValue, options, cellObject) 
    {
        return $(cellObject).is(":checked");
    }
```

This will insure that when you manipulate your data you use original data and not the formatted one

[Jqgrid Custom Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter)

**EDIT:**

I think here is the [solution](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jqgrid-how-to-retain-cellattr-conditional-formatting-while-the-datatype-is-local-or-loadonce-true/) for your issue.

Comment: i tried doing that but it was not called when "reloadGrid" is called

Comment: @user4127: I agree with AlexAr that typical problem with "disappearing" of data exist because of missing `unformat` function or because of wrong usage of `index` property in `colModel`. You should **append your question with the JavaScript code which you use**.